# MSYS2 64bit Installation Bug

Tags: installation, msys2

I recently tried to install MSYS2 64bit. However, something must have gone wrong during the installation. It seemed to have installed, but whenever I pull up VS Code, a MSYS2 64bit Setup Wizard keeps popping up, even after I x it out. I usually need to x it out 5-10 times before it goes away. I've tried uninstalling and re-installing, I've tried deleting all the files, and I've tried re-installing over the folder it wants to save its data in, but I can't seem to figure this one out.
There's probably an easy solution, I'm still a novice in the world of tech. Any tips/advice would be greatly appreciated.

I tried uninstalling/reinstalling/deleting files/copying over.

Comment: So you did something to VSC to cause this. Can you show your `settings.json`?

Comment: Here is where I think the problem is in settings.json:
"C_Cpp.default.compilerPath": "c:\\Users\\bense\\Downloads\\msys2-x86_64-20220603.exe",
  "[jsonc]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  }

What should the C_Cpp.default.compilerPath be set to? Or am I misunderstanding the cause?

Comment: Yes, it's not the right compiler path. Why did you set it like this? It should point to something like `C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin\g++.exe` or `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\g++.exe`, depending on which compiler you installed in MSYS2.

Comment: That solved it. I had to uninstall/reinstall and make sure it got the path right. Why did I set it like that? Because I'm still trying to figure it out lol. Thanks, man. I appreciate it. That bug was driving me crazy.